# Dynamic formula to summarize each column of several rows when adding rows

Tags: google-sheets

Happy 2022, all!

I have a table in which I'd like to have a totals row where the numbers from each column are summarized.

The formula below works for 2 rows (and all following columns with text in Row 2)
`=ArrayFormula(IF(COLUMN(2:2)=1,"TOTAL",IF(LEN(2:2)>0,A3:3+A4:4,"")))`

The formula below works for 3 rows (and all following columns with text in Row 2)
`=ArrayFormula(IF(COLUMN(2:2)=1,"TOTAL",IF(LEN(2:2)>0,A3:3+A4:4,"")))`
etc,

I'd like to set up a formula which I do not have to modify every time I add a row because that's both time-consuming and likely to lead to errors.  Another important preference is to be able to define a heading.  I am currently using `IF(COLUMN(2:2)=1,"TOTAL"` to do that but if the new formula requires a different solution, that's perfectly fine.

Sample file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YdV2rmvdfoFMcdPKPEmNlUWJtvzPE7-5nU1f9hIv4XU/edit#gid=0

Apologies if this question has already been answered.  In that case please link to the existing question/answer, if possible.  I looked and didn't find anything that worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third scenario shown in your sample spreadsheet, put this formula in cell `A27`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Total", 
    sumif( if(row(B20:E26), column(B20:E26)), column(B20:E26), B20:E26 ) 
  } 
)
```

Then clear row 26. When adding data, insert a row *above* row 26 to ensure the range references get expanded as your data does.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is complicated by requiring the formula to be in the same column as the data it is summing. But as an accountant in a past life, I know exactly why you would want/need/prefer it like this.

**Option#1 - Insert new rows above**

- This is the KISS solution
- In the first blank row at the bottom of the column A, enter "Insert new rows above"

  - the goal is that any new rows are to be inserted **ABOVE** this row.
- In the next blank row, enter "TOTAL", in Column A
- In the same row, enter this formula in Column B
  `=sum(B2:B10)`

  - the upper row is the first row in the range. It should include the header row if the header contains text.
  - the lower row is the row containing " Insert new rows above". (In this example,  `B10` is the row that refers to "Insert new rows above")
- copy the formula across as many columns as you have data.

Inserting new rows will ALWAYS expand the sum range. You can see the effect in the sample below

[image: insertnewrowsabove]

---

**Option#2 - A dynamic formula**

- In the first blank row at the bottom of the column A, enter "TOTAL" in Column A
- In the same row, enter this formula in Column B
  `=sum(indirect(address(2,column(),4)&":"&address(row()-1,column(),4)))`
- copy the formula across as many columns as you have data.

  - The first row in the `SUM` range is the header row (Row2)
  - The last row in the SUM range is `row()-1`; this is the row immediately above the formula, and it is calculated dynamically.
  - The column is created dynamically by `column()`

[image: indirect]